# ServiceStack OrmLite - Elegant way to handle SQL Server Connection Drops

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

We are currently using ORMLite and it is working really well.
One of the places that we are using it is for running large batch processes. 
These processes run a single large batch all within a single transaction, if there are any errors then it rolls back the transaction and then it needs to be run again.

Is there a way that something like a connection drop(which could be very quick) could be better handled and that it could then, just re-establish the connection and then re-continue from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that's resembles something close to what you're after is using a [Custom OrmLite Exec Fitler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#exec-result-and-string-filters) which you can use to inject your own custom Execution strategy.

The example on OrmLite's home page shows an example of using an Exec filter to execute each query 3 times:

```
public class ReplayOrmLiteExecFilter : OrmLiteExecFilter
{
    public int ReplayTimes { get; set; }

    public override T Exec<T>(IDbConnection dbConn, Func<IDbCommand, T> filter)
    {
        var holdProvider = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider;
        var dbCmd = CreateCommand(dbConn);
        try
        {
            var ret = default(T);
            for (var i = 0; i < ReplayTimes; i++)
            {
                ret = filter(dbCmd);
            }
            return ret;
        }
        finally
        {
            DisposeCommand(dbCmd);
            OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = holdProvider;
        }
    }
}

OrmLiteConfig.ExecFilter = new ReplayOrmLiteExecFilter { ReplayTimes = 3 };

using (var db = OpenDbConnection())
{
    db.DropAndCreateTable<PocoTable>();
    db.Insert(new PocoTable { Name = "Multiplicity" });

    var rowsInserted = db.Count<PocoTable>(x => x.Name == "Multiplicity"); //3
}
```

But it uses the same `IDbConnection`, i.e. it doesn't create a new DB Connection.